# bluetooth in large area - find bluetooth device model

Tags: c#, android, ios, bluetooth

I wanna start working on Bluetooth, and design a network by that, so i have basic question:

can i find model of phone by Bluetooth application in my server? (to send application for that model)

Comment: Try to make it short for a comment: first get the BluetoothClass for your Bluetooth device with [getBluetoothClass()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#getBluetoothClass()). Now use getMajorDeviceClass() to detect phones. Now let's go to open the connection and use listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord() to communicate, start surfing on [Bluetooth specifications](https://www.bluetooth.org/apps/content/?doc_id=49708) for details on services. It's easy to detect manufacturer but you may have more trouble to detect the exact OS/version.

Comment: In theory there is a specification for this (on the link I posted search for Device ID profile) but you have to send commands by your own (AFAIK no help from Android). Probably (if you have the opportunity to test with many devices) the easiest solution is to use read device name (from the BluetoothDevice you obtained from the first step on my first comment) and to parse it (somehow...)

Comment: tanx @Adriano! :) the link is useful, i try to find out a simple way, detecting OS is the next, i'll think on it next time! very very very tanX! :)